# pandas create new column base on another column selected value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I have a column user_id with the different user ID.
From there I want to choose certain user IDs and create another column to identify those selected user IDs belong to which group.

For e.g user IDs "attamm1, attbmm1" belong to "Vendor ABC" of another newly created column that matched the user IDs.

How can i do that, thanks!

```
#map user id
userid_list = ['attamm1', 'attbmm1']
df['Vendor ABC'] = df[df.STRUCTURALSTATUS.isin(value_list)]
```

Output:

[expected out screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obF0L.png)

Comment: Can you give example of input data and desired output? That'll help us solve your problem faster.

Comment: @ManishSaraswat Hi, i have upload the screenshot of the desired output. The column "Vendor" will be based on the user id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dict = {'attmlk1': 'CWT', 'attmmma1': 'CWT', 'attanna1': 'CWT', 'attmsl1': 'RNJ', 'kyqang1': 'RNJ'}

def f(x):
    x = str(x)
    s = dict[x]
    return s

value_list = ['attmlk1','attctl1']

df.loc[df.CREATEDBY.isin(value_list), 'Vendor'] = 
df.loc[df.CREATEDBY.isin(value_list), 'CREATEDBY']

df['Vendor'] = df['Vendor'].apply(lambda x: f(x))
```

[image: key error " 'nan']

Comment: Note: All the user ids you want in `Vendor` must be in in `value_list`. In the code above, only `'attmlk1','attctl1'` will be in the `Vendor` column.

Comment: add `'nan': None` to `dict`.

Comment: no problem :) please use the vote buttons if you think the answers were helpful. And I recommend you take a few Python courses - like [codeacademy](https://www.codecademy.com/) :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use .loc

```
df.loc[df.STRUCTURALSTATUS.isin(value_list), 'Vendor ABC'] = df.loc[df.STRUCTURALSTATUS.isin(value_list), 'user_id']
```

Comment: how can i change the name of user id in the new column Vendor ABC as another defined name such as "CWT" , instead of copy the same name from the column user_id . E.g if user id = "123" , Vendor ABC = "CWT", if user id = "456", Vendor ABC = RJ

Comment: First define a function which carry's out the map you want, so `f("123") = "CWT"` and `f("456") = "RJ-"`. Then write `df['Vendor ABC'] = df['Vendor ABC'].apply(lambda x: f(x))` below the line in my answer above.

Comment: No you need to **define** the function first! [link](https://www.python-course.eu/functions.php). `f("attmlk1") = "CWT" and f("attctl1") = "RJ"` will not work, this was an example of what fucntion you need to define.

Comment: sorry, cant get it right! def f("attmlk1" = "CWT" , "attctl1" ="RJ"):

Comment: `f("attmlk1") = "CWT" and f("attctl1") = "RJ"` this is not how you define a function. It doesnt make sense and is making the error. See my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Python function example:

```
def function_name(input):
    #do something, example
    output = input * 2
    return output
```

All I can think of is define a *dictionary* with the map you want. So

```
dict = {1:'A', 2:'B', 3:'C' ,4:'D' , ... , 9:'I'}
```

then write a function like this

```
def f(x):
    x = str(x)
    s = ''
    for i in x:
       s += dict[int(i)]
    return s
```

After defining this function you can then use it like f(123) = 'ABC'.

Do this first in your code. And delete this line `f("attmlk1") = "CWT" and f("attctl1") = "RJ"` - it doesnt make sense.

Comment: Hi, sorry i couldn't get it on how to implement on what i want to achieve. Please see my code on above.

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(x):
    x = str(x)
    s = dict[x]
    return s
```

And delete the old function definition